# Helm - Configmap - Read and update the file name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the application properties defined for each environment inside a config folder.

```
config/
application-dev.yml
application-dit.yml
application-sit.yml
```

When i'm trying to deploy the application in **dev**, i need to create configmap by considering the **applicaiton-dev.yml** with a name **application.yml**.

When i'm trying to deploy the application in **dit** i need to create configmap by considering the **application-dit.yml**. But the name of the file should be always **application.yml** inside the configmap.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When using helm to manage projects, different **values.yaml** files are generally used to distinguish between different environments (development/pre-release/online).

Suppose your configmap file is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Values.cm.name }}
data:
  application.yml : |-
    {{ $.Files.Get {{ $.Values.cm.path }} | nindent 4 }}
```

---

In dev, define values-dev.yaml file

```
cm:
  name: test
  path: config/application-dev.yml
```

When you install the chart in dev, you can use the following command:

`helm install test . -f values-dev.yaml`

---

In dit, define values-dit.yaml file

```
cm:
  name: test
  path: config/application-dit.yml
```

When you install the chart in dit, you can use the following command:

`helm install test . -f values-dit.yaml`